# Отправка датаграмм через бродкаст

Tags: linux, сокет, localhost, udp

Заранее прошу прощения, если неверно пользуюсь терминологией - новичек в этом. Так вот: имеется два `udp` сокета, один сендер, второй ресивер. Сендер посылает датаграммы по `ip` 255.255.255.255 (насколько я понял это бродкаст). При этом ресивер получает сообщения от сендера и, изначально, я думал, что он тоже слушает бродкаст, но потом обнаружил в коде условие, что если `sin_addr` равен `0xffffffff` то ничего не делай.

```
if (/*sockaddr_in*/addr.sin_addr.s_addr == 0xffffffff) {
  return;
}
```

И я хочу узнать, может ли сокет, который слушает порт вроде 198.10и.тд получать сообщение посланное через бродкаст?

Comment: А что такое в данном случае addr ? может это адрес отправителя, и он проверяет что бы отправитель имел осмысленный ip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> И я хочу узнать, может ли сокет, который слушает порт вроде 198.10и.тд получать сообщение посланное через бродкаст?

Да, так и есть. Широковещательные сообщения получают все узлы локальной подсети, слушающие на данном порту. «Слушать броадкаст» — в принципе невозможно. Более того, на уровне вызова `recvfrom ()` широковещательные сообщения не различимы от обычных.

> ```
> if (/*sockaddr_in*/addr.sin_addr.s_addr == 0xffffffff) {
> ```

Не особо понятно, то это за проверка без контекста, но если `addr` — это то что вернул `recvfrom ()`, то при корректной работе всех узлов — это не имеет смысла.

С другой стороны, это может быть проверка на броадкаст в адресе отправителя который будучи использован для ответа может вызвать лавину пакетов. В принципе, на уровне ниже IP возможно сформировать пакет с любым адресом отправителя, хотя это и не является корректным (кому-то хочется замаскироваться, или похулиганить, или …)*

<sub>* спасибо **@avp** за замечание</sub>

Comment: Это проверка броадкаст в  адресе отправителя, который будучи использован для ответа может вызвать лавину пакетов. В принципе, на уровне ниже IP я могу сформировать пакет с любым адресом отправителя (хочу замаскироваться или похулиганить или ...) в т.ч. и 0xffffffff

Comment: @avp, мм... может быть... добавлю в ответ...

Comment: Слушать бродкаст можно в raw